# Azure Kudu access for users with Lighthouse delegated permissions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have delegated access to Azure resources in a third-party tenant using [Lighthouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lighthouse/), and this works fine via the portal; users receive the roles expected (typically Contributor).

However, they are unable to access Kudu (at *webappname*.scm.azurewebsites.net), receiving an error;

> Selected user account does not exist in tenant '*Tenant Name*' and
> cannot access the application 'abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd'
> in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in
> the tenant first. Please use a different account.

If the same user account is added as a guest to the third-party tenant and given the same role, they can access Kudu as expected.

It's clear that Kudu is expecting/demanding an account in the same tenant as the application, but Azure Lighthouse delegated permissions is all about *not* having to do that.

Is there something I'm missing, or another role that needs granting?

Comment: You can refer to [User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist) and [User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant and cannot access the application in that tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/447296/user-account-from-identity-provider-does-not-exist.html)

Comment: Thanks, but those don't really help; it's clear that Kudu is expecting/demanding an account in the same tenant as the application, but Azure Lighthouse delegated permissions is all about _not_ having to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PhilD, Thanks for the detailed description of the scenario. I have also posted this on your [Q&A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/791520/kudu-via-lighthouse-delegated-permissions.html?childToView=793114#answer-793114).

Currently, Kudu is not compatible with Lighthouse-delegated permissions.

Our product engineering team is working on it; however, we do not have an exact ETA to share.
We’re expecting it to be available in a few months. Please note that this timeline is just an estimate and is subject to change, depending on a myriad of factors.

I have relayed the feedback internally to our product engineering team and it’s being tracked.

-On **a side note**, as mentioned in this [Kudu wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service#security) :
“*Only those with Contributor / Owner access (to be exact, with microsoft.web/sites/publish/action or, for slot, microsoft.web/sites/slots/publish/action) can access to Kudu (SCM).*”

Much appreciate your valuable feedback on this. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Many thanks for confirming that Kudu is not compatible with Lighthouse-delegated permissions. That's unfortunate, but at least I now know it's not something I got wrong!

Comment: Glad to know that the information was helpful.
No worries, thanks Phil for the follow-up.  As mentioned above, your feedback is heard. Our team is looking into this.

Comment: Is there a UserVoice/GitHub issue or somewhere I can track it, just so I know when it is available?

Comment: You may track this on Uservoice: [Grant access to Kudu services (Advanced Tools/ Logging) for delegated Contributors][1].

  [1]: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/da0291ea-f824-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0